# python error message min() arf is an empty sequence

Tags: min

I am trying to create a function that takes up a string of numbers and outputs the maximum and minimum values. Here is my code

```
def high_and_low(numbers):
    numbers = map(int, numbers.split())
    max_n = max(numbers)
    print(max_n)    
    min_n = min(numbers)
    return(max_n, min_n)
```

But I get the following error: ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence. So I assume that it does not read the negative values, but I dont know why..

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using Python 3.x, where `map()` was changed to return a generator rather than an explicit list of results as in Python 2.x.  Calling `max()` on this generator exhausted it, leaving no elements for `min()` to iterate over.

One solution would be to convert this generator to a list, perhaps `numbers = list(numbers)` as the second line of your function.  As a list, you can iterate it as many times as you need to.

Comment: Thanks, I still got an issue though, because my output should be a string, instead of a numerical array. I tried to do map(str) on the max and min, but it did not work